# VBA To loop each cell in the Column A in excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

In my excel in the column A, there are some date format and some text, I need to identity if each cell in column A if it is a date format or not date format:
Below is my code i try to loop each cell, but it identifies only cell A2, ANy help and ideas . Thanks

```
   Dim strDate As String
         
   Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
   Set rng = Range("A2:A17")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")

    For Each cell In rng
    MsgBox (cell.Value)
    

    
    strDate = .Range("A2").Value
    If IsDate(strDate) Then
        MsgBox "This is a date format"
        
        Else
        MsgBox "This is not a date format"
         
       End If
       Next cell
   
    
     End With
      End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are assigning .range("A2") to strDate; use the cell object from the for each loop:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckDates()

    Dim strDate As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("A2:A17")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In rng
            MsgBox (cell.Value)
            strDate = cell.Value
            If IsDate(strDate) Then
                MsgBox "This is a date format"
            Else
                MsgBox "This is not a date format"
            End If
        Next cell
     End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have many lines to check is better to use an array which is faster:

```
Sub test()
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")
    
        arr = .Range("A2:A17")
        
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        
            If IsDate(arr(i, 1)) Then
                MsgBox "This is a date format"
            Else
                MsgBox "This is not a date format"
            End If
            
        Next i
        
    End With
       
End Sub
```